# Why doesn't my drop-down menu stay visible when I hover over it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Okay, so I've got two drop-down menus on my page, Navigation, and Links. Links works normally, but Navigation disappears when I try to hover over it. I got no idea why, so I'm asking.
Why does my Navigation menu disappear when I hover over it, and how do I fix it?

[My site with the error](http://cypri.231days.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an element that's hanging over the left menu named `#crwrap`. So when moving your mouse to the Navigation options, the mouseout is triggered because you're suddenly hovering the `#crwrap` element instead of the Navigation menu. It's invisible but if you use a debugging tool that supports DOM searching you'll see it covering the area of the Navigation menu options.

It's not covering the Links menu so that one does not have any problems.

If you remove `#crwrap` (or move it to the background using `z-index: -999`), it works fine for me.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Your JS to show the menus is toggled by mouseover and mouseout of the elements in your menu section. The submenus are not nested inside these elements. Therefore, when you move the mouse down toward the submenu, you trigger the mouseout on the main menu item, which is hiding the submenu.

I would recommend nesting the submenu items inside the main menu item's container.

I would also advise you check out the excellent alistapart.com article about [CSS hybrid menus](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/hybrid/). It has some excellent pointers and techniques you might find useful.

Comment: So why does the Links menu work and Navigation not? They're coded the same way.

Comment: You're using toggle, which switches between hidden and shown. On the first menu you're getting an odd number of hover events, the second an even number. `$("#linklink, #linksmenu, #navilink, #navimenu").hover(function() { console.log('hovering over ' + this.id); })`

Comment: okay, I copy and pasted them in the main menu to see if it'd work, but I'm still getting the same error. you can see it on my site, I uploaded it.